# form submitted data from template is not saved in database in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-views

I was doing a small project on Django where I create a simple blog mini-project. Everything worked for me but I am in issue now that I can create a post form Django administration and I wanted to do it within front-end with templates in create-post.html but I am no issue just my form is not working or it is not submitting any data or some error?

I'm using summer note rich text editor instead of the text field in Model. Experts please look at my code and suggest to me it is good or bad or where I am wrong?

my models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author_profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    author_description = models.TextField(null=True)
    author_facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    author_twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    author_instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    author_github_url = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    def __str__(self): 
        return f'{self.user}'

class Category(models.Model): # show string title in Admin panel
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Blogpost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    post_body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True,blank=True)
    posted_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    publish = models.BooleanField()
```

and my form

```
from django import forms
from .models import Blogpost
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget


class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blogpost
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            'post_body': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

and views.py

```
def create(request):
    form = CreatePostForm
    return render(request,'create-post.html',{'form':form})

def createpost(request):
  form = CreatePostForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect('homepage')

  else:
    form = CreatePostForm()
  return render(request, "create-post.html", {'form': form})
```

and urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.homepage,name='homepage'),
    path('create',views.create,name='create'),
    path('createpost',views.createpost,name='createpost')
]
```

create-post.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h3> Creating Post</h3>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'createpost' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form|safe }}

    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm in the learning phase so can anyone tell me where I am wrong? but it is working from Django-administration but not working through templates.

Comment: Can you add the template to the question? I have a feeling you are not calling the correct view in the `action` attribute of your form

Comment: I edited the question and added the create-post.html template. You can check now.

Comment: You can use `{{form.errors}}` tag to display errors in the template

Comment: {{form.errors}} shows an error that  " thumbnail, This field is required. " but i selected the image in the field.

Comment: did you setup `summernote` correctly? Please check this [repo](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote)

Comment: Thank you all of you for comment, I got solution that there was request.FILES was missing in my views.py so i corrected it myself and it is working well now.